How to revert NixOS channel version back to the version used in specific boot entry (generation)?
I'm running NixOS unstable, and I've done nixos-rebuild boot --upgrade few times, and figured out some app is broken. It is probably some temporary incompatibility / breaking change in dependencies, that will eventually get resolved.
I managed to identify, and I'm running (booted), the fully working generation now:

the fully working generation is a few generations back - not the previous one.

Now, next I would like to get to the state before those upgrades:

I want to revert to the fully working generation:

make it the default boot generation,
or create a new (identical) one placed on top of all generations,


I want to revert nix channel to version used by this generation:

be able to make changes to configuration.nix and apply them with nixos-rebuild.




This question is similar to: How to rollback a channel to a previous Nixos generation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ChrisStryczynski looking at that question. Title is different. Content actually seems similar. The answers there however are not helpful for a beginner-level NixOS user, such as me. The answer by l0b0 is very useful.

@ChrisStryczynski close this question if you like. But, in that question OP wants to go to previous generation (but multiple channel updates), but here the question is going more generations back. The core of the problem in the end, is the same. However, for beginner level users, approaching the same core problem from different position (previous/further back, multiple updates,..) it might not be so obvious at the first time. Many times I find answers in questions closed as duplicates on S/E, and not in the original question.

It is a very useful answer below, so I've retracted my close/duplicate vote. I really don't like marking questions as duplicates. My intention was just to highlight the similar question. Ideally I think it'd be good to merge these two questions but I'm not sure how that works.

You can use this to revert to the currently running generation: sudo nix-channel --rollback "$(grep --files-with-matches --fixed-strings "$(cut --delimiter=. --fields=3 /run/current-system/nixos-version)" /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels-*-link/nixos/svn-revision | cut --delimiter=- --fields=3 | sort --numeric-sort | tail --lines=1)". Explanation, grouped by subshells:

sudo nix-channel --rollback N reverts channels to generation N.

grep --files-with-matches --fixed-strings TEXT PATHS lists the paths in PATHS which contain the literal string TEXT.

cut --delimiter=. --fields=3 PATH gets the third dot-separated fields in PATH. /run/current-system/nixos-version has contents with the format "MAJOR.MINOR_AND_SOME_UNKNOWN_GUFF.HASH", so that means the HASH part of the file. That is the TEXT in the grep above.
/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels-*-link/nixos/svn-revision expands to all the svn-revision files in each generation of the current system (in alphabetical order). That is the PATHS in the grep above.


cut --delimiter=- --fields=3 pulls out the generation number from the file paths.
sort --numeric-sort sorts the generation numbers numerically, rather than alphabetically.
tail --lines=1 gives us the last line, that is, the most recent generation number.




Thank you! Although it's a barely elaborate answer, the one-liner solved my problem - I did break it apart, and inspected what the substitution is doing, before running the whole command. The sudo nix-channel --rollback N did reset the nixos channel back to the version used by currently running generation. To create new default boot generation, I still needed to run nixos-rebuild boot after the rollback.
